# How to hide my comment box automatically after clicking post using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, css

i've made my comment box now i wanted to design it myself as after click "post" button it would be automatically hide with spade, actually i've made this on Menu i mean when user would click into menu (like facebook notification menu) and this box will show up and after submitting post it will automatically disappear, Now please help how to do this?

Here is my script for form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

    /* This flag will prevent multiple comment submits: */
    var Posting = false;

    /* Listening for the submit event of the form: */
    $('#addCommentForm').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        if(Posting) return false;

        posting = true;
        $('#submit').val('Posting..');
        $('span.error').remove();

        /* Sending the form fileds to submit.php: */
        $.post('submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){

            working = false;
            $('#submit').val('Post');

            if(msg.status){

                /* 
                /   If the insert was successful, add the comment
                /   below the last one on the page with a slideDown effect
                /*/

                $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addPostingContainer').slideDown();
                $('#body').val('');
            }
            else {

                /*
                /   If there were errors, loop through the
                /   msg.errors object and display them on the page 
                /*/

                $.each(msg.errors,function(k,v){
                    $('label[for='+k+']').append('<span class="error">'+v+'</span>');
                });
            }
        },'json');

    });

});
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "hide with spade" but you can hide any elements you want with `$().hide()` (for example) in your posting code.  What have you actually tried in terms of hiding them?

Comment: Can you hide it or not tell me straight?

Comment: You can hide any element you want.  Select the element with jQuery and call .hide() on that.  E.g. `$('#foo').hide()` to hide an element with id "foo".  However I do not know what you mean by hiding something "with spade".